# creating a mesh similar to the image:

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, workflow

[image]

Help me to create a mesh similar to that of the drawing in bold below.  Excuse me for my bad drawing skills.

Answer (score 8):

- Add a UV sphere (Add>Mesh>UV Sphere)
- set selection mode to *faces* :
  [image]
- select the *faces* you want to keep
- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to invert the selection
- press <kbd>X</kbd>, and select *delete faces*.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You might want more universal method, depending on what's your goal exactly.
Theres a modifier [Shrinkwrap](https://www.blender.org/manual/modifiers/deform/shrinkwrap.html) that projects one mesh to another. So you can project a mesh with complicated topology to another mesh (very useful for retopology for example).

Add base object (as a base for shape) and a plane (which will be projected on the base shape object):
[image: Add a sphere and a plane]

Add Shrinkwrap modifier to the object you want to modify (plane in this example) and use sphere as a target object.
[image: Project one mesh to another]

Answer (score 8):

Another way this can be done is using two bend modifiers and an empty.

First add a plane, and then add two loop cuts in each direction. In edit mode, rotate it by 90<sup>o</sup> on the X axis.

Next add an empty and rotate it by 90<sup>o</sup> on the Y axis

Finally, add two simple deform modifiers and set them to bend.
on the second one, change to origin to your empty.

[image]

You should end up with this:

[image]

This method has an advantage over the other two - it can be adjusted.

[image]